# How many ways are there to perform the 83 serves when 3 types of serves are being used?

Tags: combinatorics

> The player hits 83 serves in his first round match. For each
> one he randomly chooses between the variants slice, kick and flat. How
> many ways are there to perform the 83 serves?

We have an algorithm to answer such questions:

1. Decide whether to look at all elements or just a sample.
2. Decide if the order / arrangement is important.
3. Decide if the elements can be repeated.
4. Select formula.
5. Choose n and k .

I'm getting a bit lost here. We're viewing all 83 serves, correct? Or are we viewing the subset of 3? Does the order matter or not? I dont think it does. The player can choose any type of server he wants to.

Comment: You are viewing all 83 serves, where for each serve the player may perform it three different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are viewing all the $83$ serves.
Notice that the wording is: "How many ways are there to perform the 83 serves?" implying that you want to know the **sequence** of serves. Because it is a sequence, the order does matter.

Yes, but the player has a choice out of $3$ in every one of the $83$ serves. If there were $2$ serves, then how many choices you have? Extend to $83.$

Comment: So the soution is 83^3 ?

Comment: @HaiseSasaki No. Did you get $2^3$ solutions for the case of $2$ serves? Or you got $3^2$?

Comment: Let's step back for a moment. It says here, if we look at the entire set/all elements, it's a permutation. A subset is a variation or combination. So we're talking about a permutation, right?

Comment: No. A permutation is when you are looking at the entire set but there is **no** repetition allowed. Here you do not need to use all elements and you can repeat them. It is a sequence. For example: if the question was, in how many ways can you use the $3$ type of serves in $3$ rounds where you dont use a serve twice. That is a permutation.

Comment: I see, my bad. Thank you!

Comment: @HaiseSasaki You are welcome!